# Simple bash script - concatenating strings

Tags: string, macos, bash, loops, for-loop

i'm learning bash scripting and i wrote this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(cat test.csv | cut -d';' -f 4)
do
EXT=".pdf"
echo "$f$EXT"
done
```

Where the file test.csv is:

```
col1;col2;col3;test1
col1;col2;col3;test2
col1;col2;col3;test3
...
```

the output of this script is:

```
.pdf
.pdf
.pdf
...
```

The output expected would be:

```
test1.pdf
test2.pdf
test3.pdf
...
```

Sorry for stupid questions but i'm stuck in this, i think, little problem.

Same output with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=\; read col1 col2 col3 col4
do
echo "$col4".pdf
done < test.csv
```

Comment: Is it your real test.csv? You're extracting the 4th column among columns separated by semicolon, but your example doesn't have 4th column.

Comment: Yeah, the content of test.csv interested in is the 4th column. Fixed.

Comment: If test.csv indeed has 4 columns or more, edit your question and show the real example (where we can see 4 columns even if they're uninteresting).

Comment: Just tried your original for loop and it works fine for me. Is there anything else in the script that you've cut out perhaps? Alternatively, are you sure there aren't control characters in your input file `test.csv`? BTW How are you running the script?

Comment: Importato to note that the script work with oncly `echo "$col4"` without .pdf string. I run it via macosx terminal ./script

Comment: Beware: UUOC Award on its way.  Use `cut -d';' -f 4 test.csv` instead.  Since you seem to be having problems, maybe you should show the output of: `cat test.csv` and then `cut -d';' -f 4 test.csv`.  One of them is likely to show what is going wrong; it is likely that the file does not contain what you think it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do `for i in $(cat something)`. It will keep the whole file in memory which isn't needed. Also it doesn't work with whitespace in columns.

Better parse line by line, and use shell tools to split the columns (the `read` builtin).

Something along the lines of

```
while IFS=\; read col1 col2 col3 col4
do
    echo "$col4".pdf
done < test.csv
```

should do.

You can remove the `IFS=\;` part if your columns are separated by whitespace instead.

Comment: To simplify i created a file test with the output of `cat test.csv | cut -d';' -f 4 >> test` and modified the script: `while read f do echo "$f".pdf done < test` and actually the output it's the same of my script. A long list of ".pdf"...

Comment: Not working yet...always a list of .pdf .pdf .pdf. ... it's something like he loose the value of $col4

Comment: @Kartone: Yes it works. If it doesn't for you, then you probably use a different test set than the one you provided to us.

Comment: i'll try to change test file.

Answer (score 1):

Or use sed:

```
sed  's/.*;\(.*\)/\1.pdf/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        LINE=`echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $4}'`
        echo "${LINE}.pdf"
done < test.csv
```